# How to build a relationship between consecutive records in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a data file like:

```
Top executives  11-1000 Summary \n
Chief executives    11-1011 Line item \n
General and operations managers 11-1021 Line item \n
Legislators 11-1031 Line item \n
```

I want to read this data file using PIG and achieve an output covering the  summary and the line items in a single row like:

```
Top executives Chief executives 11-1011 \n
Top executives General and operations managers 11-1021 \n
Top executives Legislators  11-1031 \n
```

Can somebody help me with some ideas for this ?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what relation you are looking here. I see only Top executives appended to all the rows..

Comment: Could you also specify the input and the desired output schema?